# mod_rewrite и решетка # - PHP

Tags: php, get, mod-rewrite

Как обработать URL:

```
 http://site.ru/goods/test6/#/?brand[]=6&price_to=9999999999&sg=1&brand[]=12
```

И выделить GET параметры

Пробую вот так, но не выходит

```
RewriteRule ^goods/(.*)/#/(/?)+$ index.php?do=goods&id_s=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: А где здесь php? Я вижу только один RewriteRule. Для обработки GET параметров в `mod_rewrite` используйте `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}`.

Comment: Вроде бы все что после хеша не передавалось на сервер?

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение.

```
RewriteRule ^goods/(.*)/\x23/(/?)+$ index.php?do=goods&id_s=$1 [NE,QSA,L]
```

Comment: `^goods/(.*)/\#/(/?)+$` - экранировать не работало?

Comment: Нет, экранирование здесь не работает.